# SELECT INTO returning 0 for @@ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help with the following, I'm trying to batch my inserts. If I omit the batching code (i.e. just run the SELECT..INTO) it works fine and over 1m rows are inserted. If I use the following, the loop is exiting immediately with a zero row count. Wrapping in a transaction has no effect either.

```
DECLARE @id_control INT
DECLARE @batchSize INT
DECLARE @results INT

SET @results = 1 
SET @batchSize = 10000 
SET @id_control = 0 
WHILE (@results > 0) 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        field1,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by case when n.field2>0 then n.field2 else n.field3 end order by field3 desc) as DupNum
    into #nadtemp      
    FROM table2 n
        join table3 tex ON n.SAU=tex.SAU
        join table4 e on e.sau=n.sau
        left join #usednad u on u.Nadkey=n.Nad_key
    where  u.Nadkey is null 
    and u.id>@id_control
    and u.id<=@id_control+@batchSize

    SET @results = @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @id_control = @id_control + @batchSize
END
```

My output is this:

(0 rows affected)
0

Completion time: 2020-11-25T19:59:40.4467761+00:00

Comment: How are you outputting it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] as it stands its unreproducible.

Comment: ok, sorry, I'll update my question with the full sql

Comment: where u.Nadkey is null ...contradicts the equality/comparison u.id>@id_control etc. The u table is left joined...you are asking for rows which do not match the join..but also are equal/greater than a value. u rows cannot be null and have a value at the same time..

Comment: If you are trying to left join onto a subset of `#usednad` the `u.id>@id_control and u.id<=@id_control+@batchSize` should be in the `ON` clause not the `WHERE` clause. Otherwise it is contradictory as @lptr states. I'm not convinced that left joining onto a moving subset is really what you need though

Comment: Yes, thanks, my mistake that check was producing no data, rather tthan the rowcount was returning zero for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

> is select..into should be populating @@rowcount`

Yes it is correct. [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @result INT;

SELECT field1, field2,row_number() over (partition by field1 ORDER BY field2) rn
into #temp1
FROM (VALUES (1,2),(2,3),(4,5)) s(field1, field2)

SET @result =  @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT @result;
-- 3
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc95f44233860707561eb683f088546d)**

Comment: apologies, I was trying to simplify my code to focus on the fault I thought I had, I've re-edited the question.